# Binding link button with css

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, linkbutton

I am new in asp.net so this can be stupid question.I have few link buttons in my project.They are all initially blue and I want to change their color.I tried this

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbHome" runat="server" onclick="lbPocetna_Click" CssClass="link">Home</asp:LinkButton> &nbsp
```

And I add this in Site.css

```
.link {
color:Maroon;}
```

But nothing happened.Where is my mistake pls tell me.

Comment: Change to .link:link {color:Maroon;}

Answer (score 1):

If you already have some anchor Pseudo-classes in your css file like;

```
a:link {color:#FF0000;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
```

Then you will need to add in;

```
.link:link{ color: Maroon; }
```

However this will still leave the colour as the original `:visited' /`:hover`/`:active`, so you would want to add all of these.

```
.link:visited{ color: Maroon; }
.link:hover{ color: Maroon; }
.link:active{ color: Maroon; }
```